# legend navigation arrows do not appear on second responsiveness driven chart.update

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

Using highcharts, i'd like my chart to move its legend from the bottom to the right hand side if it's height is below a given value.

This can be done using the responsive rules array.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive

It works well first time it is applied, but the second time the rule is applied, navigation arrows will not appear (see fiddle below). This looks like a bug, not reported in highcharts forum.

http://jsfiddle.net/58atuzmx/2/

```
condition: {
   maxHeight: 190,
},
chartOptions: {
   legend: {
     align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        layout: 'vertical'
      }
}
```

I am would like to have a workaround for navigations arrows to be displayed correctly after responsive styling rules have been applied once and are size conditions are again met.

Comment: It is a bug. I reported it [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6322). As a workaround you can try to remove svg elements responsible for navigation arrows. http://jsfiddle.net/4n1r8wya/

Comment: Thanks, it works. In my real case scenario I had to destroy box and clipRect as well for the arrows not to overlap text.